# Windows Service Timer Not Firing

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service whose timer doesn't want to fire. I have an attached debugger but it gave me no useful information. The odd thing is; that this service is nearly identical to another service I built which works as intended.

The code in question is this:

```
public Constructor()
{
    _timer.Interval += 300000;
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    //_timer.Start(); <this is not actually here. just one of the things i tried
    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
}
```

After which I have:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWorkHere();
}
```

I dont understand why attaching the "ElapsedEventHandler" doesn't fire the timer_Tick method.

Edit: "_timer" is:

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Comment: Call the `.Start()` method, attach the event handler **before**. Please follow this [guide](https://blog.mikejmcguire.com/2014/05/19/creating-a-wcf-enabled-windows-service/)

Comment: I guess that would make sense. But while debugging, I can't even see the event being attached.

Comment: What do you mean? Put a shorter interval of 3000 and move the start after the  `_timer.Elapsed += `... you can aslo use a temporary file/logger instead of debbugging

Comment: I am using a little ghetto logger i wrote haha. But that wasnt giving me anything so i attached a debugger. But yeah, ill give that a go. thanks.

Comment: Log also the fact that you are in the constructor and the timer is started, otherwise it means that you have a different problem in the service definition

Comment: Just to give you a laugh. Apparently everything worked fine. It was my access to certain network folders that wasn't set up right. Thank you $Company.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, OP did fix the problem but the answer was not clarified as an "Answer".

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with permissions.
Sorry for wasting anyone's time.